# Pydev - startup

Tags: console, pydev, startup

Maybe I got simple questions so I googled it but I can't find answer.

I am using Pydev/Eclipse and I want to run the script within Console. 
First I want to modify the startup of the session - it means some modules are loaded during start (math, numpy, scipy, etc...). 
Where/how can I modify Pydev Console startup?

Secondly, I execute the script using righ-click on script file and "Run as -> Python Run" then it's executed within console and terminated. So I want to stay within Console and to be interactive and not be terminated. 
How can I get such feature?

Thank you!

Best regards,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

The startup configuration can be found in the PyDev preferences menu. The preferences can be found in the upper menubar under 'Window'.
Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Interactive Console
There you will find a big text input field with a label 'Initial interpreter commands'. Often it is allready in use and imports sys only to print the name and version number of the starting console.

The only solution I am aware of for staying connected with your script is to set a breakpoint at the end and start your script in debug mode. But maybe there is another way. To do so just double click at the left corner of the editor window with your script opened. A green dot will appear marking a breakpoint. Now right click an choose 'Debug As'. Your script will run till the line is reached where you have set the breakpoint.

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is the interactive console. See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

You can configure the initial commands in the preferences page.