# Run IPython by default and show at startup in Eclipse PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

As there were no satisfying answers in the following links

[Set default directory of Pydev interactive console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997877/set-default-directory-of-pydev-interactive-console)

[Pydev - startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732856/pydev-startup)

[pydev console path for the active editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051028/pydev-console-path-for-the-active-editor)

I'm asking whether there is a way to have IPython as integrated console, opening up at start up and being the console, where the modules are run by default, just like in RStudio.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's no feature to open it at startup by default, but you can do Ctrl+Alt+Enter to first open it and after it's opened, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> again to execute the current file in that console...

Alternatively, you may also use <kbd>F2</kbd> to send the current line to the console (and jump to the next line, so, it's easy to send a block with multiple <kbd>F2</kbd> keystrokes -- and it should also fix for the indentation required).

See: http://www.pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html for more details.